# Collections usable in a class denoted as a Fault Bean for a @WebFault

Tags: java, web-services, soap

All examples I've found of classes denoted as @WebFault for a SOAP web service contain an array of Fault Beans, and the class denoted as the fault bean contain an int, a String, and sometimes a List .

My webservice makes use of a build-step using java2ws to create the wsdl.

Question 1) can a SOAP webservice have more than one @WebFault? One would think so.

Question 2) can the fault bean class take a Set? and can the elements in the set be classes ie Set ?

The goal here is to propagate JSR-303 bean validation failures from the server back to the web service client where a form is waiting to be updated with 0,1, or >1 error messages.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Question 3) can the @WebFault class take a Set<> instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

1)  Yes, a single operation can have multiple faults, just like in Java a method can throw more than one checked exception

2) Not sure exactly what you're asking.

Let me just show one quick example of what you can do..maybe it points you in a helpful direction:

```
// MyIntf.java
@WebService
public interface MyIntf {

@WebMethod
void myMethod() throws MyFault;

//...
}

// MyFault.java

@WebFault(faultBean="mypkg.MyFaultBean")
public class MyFault extends Exception {

private MyFaultBean bean;

public MyFault(MyFaultBean bean, String message) {
    super(message);
    this.bean = bean;
}

public MyFault(MyFaultBean bean, String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.bean = bean;
}

public MyFaultBean getFaultInfo() {
    return bean;
}
}

// MyFaultBean.java
public class MyFaultBean {

    private Set mySet;

    public Set getMySet() {
        return mySet;
    }

    public void setMySet(Set mySet) {
        this.mySet = mySet;
    }
    //...
}
```

So you're trying to use JAXB and JAX-WS to map between Java exceptions and WSDL faults (putting it that way might help your searches).

One thing to consider is whether to approach this top-down (WSDL/XSD primary, Java secondary) or bottom-up (Java primary).

If you don't already have a fixed Java interface that you're trying to use (sounds like you may not, but maybe you do), you might be better off starting from WSDL/XSD, then using wsdl2java to generate the Java interface, then maybe customizing it a bit using JAXB customizations.

A couple more links on the subject [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WSGET/jax-ws-soapfaults.htm#WSGET637) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsca_businessexcepsca.html), (the latter mentions "SCA" but this uses JAX-WS and JAXB so is relevant).